# bower install 'dev' version of a package doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables, bower-install

I intend to use a certain feature of `angular-datatables`, namely: creating filter input fields below individual columns. A [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hwZmQOPjpNth8T8YuWyr?p=preview).

This feature is available only in the `dev` version of the package.

I set `"angular-datatables": "dev"` version in my `bower.json` `"dependencies"` object, and issued:

```
$ bower install --save
bower not-cached    git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#dev
bower resolve       git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#dev
bower checkout      angular-datatables#dev
bower resolved      git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#3c05e6a2f9
bower install       angular-datatables#3c05e6a2f9

angular-datatables#3c05e6a2f9 bower_components/angular-datatables
├── angular#1.2.26
├── datatables#1.10.2
└── jquery#2.1.1
```

The contents of bower_components/angular-datatables ended up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPUxy.jpg).

Next, I tried clearing my browser cache. Repeated the step above, still the version of `angular-datatables` remains to be `0.2.0`.

I also tried issuing `bower cache clean`, followed by a `bower install --save`, but in vain.

`$ bower info angular-datatables` tells me that the following versions are available:

```
bower angular-datatables#*      cached git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#0.2.0
bower angular-datatables#*    validate 0.2.0 against git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#*

{
  name: 'angular-datatables',
  version: '0.2.0',
  author: 'l-lin',
  main: 'dist/angular-datatables.js',
  ignore: [
    '.bowerrc',
    '.editorconfig',
    '.git*',
    '.jshintrc',
    'Gruntfile.js',
    'test',
    'node_modules',
'src',
'.travis.yml',
'vendor',
'data.json',
'data1.json',
'demo',
'favicon.png',
'index.html',
'README.md',
'server',
'styles',
'_config.yml',
'grunt',
'images',
'package.json'
  ],
  dependencies: {
    angular: '>=1.2.6',
    jquery: '>=1.11.0',
    datatables: '>=1.9.4'
  },
  devDependencies: {
    'angular-mocks': '1.2.6',
    bootstrap: '3.0.1',
    'angular-bootstrap': '0.10.0'
  },
  homepage: 'https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables'
}

Available versions:
  - 0.2.0
  - 0.1.1
  - 0.1.0
  - 0.0.3
  - 0.0.2
  - 0.0.1
```

Next, I reverted back to `v0.2.0`, and then used the install command with a `#dev` suffix.

```
 $ bower install angular-datatables#dev --save
 bower angular-datatables#dev       not-cached git://github.com/l-lin/angular-     datatables.git#dev
 bower angular-datatables#dev          resolve git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#dev
 bower angular-datatables#0.2.0         cached git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#0.2.0
 bower angular-datatables#0.2.0       validate 0.2.0 against git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#0.2.0
 bower angular-datatables#dev         checkout dev
 bower angular-datatables#dev         resolved git://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git#83ce3847da

 Unable to find a suitable version for angular-datatables, please choose one:
     1) angular-datatables#dev which resolved to 83ce3847da
     2) angular-datatables#0.2.0 which resolved to 0.2.0 and is required by zap-adm-ang
 Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

 ? Answer:: 1
```

This updated my `bower.json` file, to `"angular-datatables": "dev"`, however when I open the `angular-datatables.js` file in the `bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/` directory, the version still remains `0.2.0`. The problem persists.

[Here](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/36#issuecomment-59035447) is my discussion of the issue with the `angular-datatables` package maintainer (in case I missed out on some details).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that the package maintainer suggested is to use the following (upcoming) version of angular-datatables:

`/*!
 * angular-datatables - v0.2.1
 * https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables
 * License: MIT
 */`

which is currently available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/dev/dist/angular-datatables.min.js) and should soon be released.

Did the trick for me. The feature is available.

I am still really curious as to why the above-described process of `#dev` version installation didn't work for me.